# pre building python script before building android application on eclipse

Tags: android, pre-build-event

```
I want to run a python script before building my application,
i  added the script path to the external tools following:

project properties  > Builders > New > program > file.py location
```

and when i click on Ok after adding the path i get the following error.

```
Create Process error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

what is this error and how to run the script before building the project. please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

created a bat file with the path of the python file and also added project path to the working directory path. Now its building as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Call `python "$(SolutionDir)\your_script.py"`

You have to add python.exe to your PATH environment variable.